# Printing text files with 320 columns per line from Windows XP via IE or notepad

Tags: windows-xp, command-line, internet-explorer, printing, notepad

I am trying to print plain text files which are just formatted reports. The reports are standardized at 320 characters per line.

They are printed on A3 paper in landscape. We use a Tally MT691 printer. And the computers running on Windows XP

I have noticed that when i print this text file from the windows command prompt using the print command, the printer is able to print upto 320 characters.

But when i print the same text file by opening it in the IE(vesion 6) and from the notepad, the printer truncates after 159 columns and wraps after 146 columnns respectively.

How can i achieve the command line printing behavior from notepad/IE.. Am i doing something wrong? Can somebody please help.

Comment: I don't suspect this to be a printer specific problem because the same works from command line.

Comment: Have you tried printing from another browser / more recent version of IE? And what kind of file is it exactly?

Comment: @matan129 It is a transaction report.. So i have data separated by white space.. A line can have data like Tran_ID Tran_Date Srl_Num Particulars Remarks Created_user Created_time etc., Multiple lines with such data. I have not tried to print from more recent version of IE..

Comment: I was wondering if there is any direct print command from GUI which is equivalent to the print on command line

Comment: From what you said by now, I think it's only some kind of compatibility issue with IE6. Try printing from another browser (I recommend  [FireFox](http://firefox.com/) from the bottom of my heart).

Comment: I agree, it sounds like a formatting problem, IE seems to be adding margins or something similar.

Comment: Update: I upgraded the IE to version 7 and i was able to print all the 320 characters. But the line feed would not go in. If 10 lines were to be printed, all the ten lines are printed over the same line.

I suspected it to be EOL difference in unix and windows however, both files are printed the same way

Answer (score 0):

**Why does it happen?**

When you use the command line print command, the data is sent straight to the printer without any modification. Thus all the data is printed as long as the data lies within the printable area of the paper loaded in the printer.

When you use an application - notepad or IE. The data is formatted by the application (and the printer driver) before sending it to the printer. In order to get the correct formatting, you will have to select the correct paper size and margin.

**How to do it?**

- Open the file in the application.
- Go to print dialog (ctrl+p) and ensure that correct printer is selected (if you have multiple printers selected).
- Then go to File Menu (alt+f) and select "Page Setup". Ensure that A3
  paper size is selected and orientation is landscape.
- Also you may set the margin values to 0. Please note the application
  will reset the margin value to some minimum value based on the
  printer that you use.
- Click ok and print the job.

You may also File>"Print Preview" in IE to check if the data is formatted properly for the print.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The printer is a Generic/Text Only printer and no printer specific drivers are present. Meanwhile, the page setup, margin values are all right. Even the print preview on IE 6 shows the entire length to be printed but it just doesn't print it